# Irritable Bowel Syndrome Constipation - Soluble Fibre Foods

Tags: nutrition, gastroenterology, fibre, irritable-bowel-syndrome

I've heard that a recommended diet for constipation related to irritable bowel syndrome is to increase the amount of soluble and decrease the amount of insoluble fiber.

I have a trouble understanding which foods are high in which fiber because various websites give conflicting results.

For example, [this source](https://www.northottawawellnessfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/NOWF-Fiber-Content-of-Foods.pdf) says that beans and many vegetables are high in both soluble and insoluble fiber. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: I might consider taking out the last part asking for "other advice", as that makes it both personal opinion and very broad, both of which would be close reasons.

Comment: @JohnP plus that may be interpreted as asking for medical advice.

Comment: Have you tried to research "high soluble fiber foods" or "soluble vs insoluble fiber foods?" If you show some research in your question you may elicit a better answer.

Comment: I have, but so many differernt sites say different things. Some sites even contridict one a other. It's hard to actually know what isn't or is soluble fibre to be honest. Some sites say one food item is soluble where another says it's insoluble.

Comment: I edited the question. There can be actually some confusion which foods are high in soluble or insoluble fiber, because some foods are high i both. Also, treatment of IBS may not be as simple as just to increase some type of fiber. It's obviously an interesting question so I voted for reopening.